# How do I get my app to build when it uses the "Codename One CodeScaner Library" extension

Tags: codenameone

I had already mentioned this topic in another post and I need to take it up again.

I am working with Netbeans 12 on Windows 10

Steps performed:

1. Create the app on the "start.codenameone.com" platform with the necessary parameters.
2. Add the extension in Control Center.
3. On the library that Maven generated (common), I press the right button and solve the problems.
4. Clean and Build the application.

The window for assigning a temporary signature is not displayed, but the build process terminates with the message "BUILD SUCCESS".

I add the console output for your evaluation.

cd C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\tarifataxipredictiva; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11" cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd" -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 cn1:settings"
Scanning for projects...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Build Order:

```
tarifataxipredictiva                                               [pom]
tarifataxipredictiva-cn1libs                                       [pom]
cn1-codescan                                                       [pom]
tarifataxipredictiva-common                                        [jar]

--------< com.innova507.tarifapredictiva:tarifataxipredictiva >---------
Building tarifataxipredictiva 1.0-SNAPSHOT                         [1/4]
--------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------

--- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.97:settings (default-cli) @ tarifataxipredictiva ---

----< com.innova507.tarifapredictiva:tarifataxipredictiva-cn1libs >-----
Building tarifataxipredictiva-cn1libs 1.0-SNAPSHOT                 [2/4]
--------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------

--- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.97:settings (default-cli) @ tarifataxipredictiva-cn1libs ---
Failed to find CN1 Project directory.  codenameone_settings.properties will not be loaded
Checking from project root and source compile root: C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\tarifataxipredictiva\cn1libs\src\main\java

--< com.innova507.tarifapredictiva:tarifataxipredictiva-cn1-codescan >--
Building cn1-codescan 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                 [3/4]
--------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------

--- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.97:settings (default-cli) @ tarifataxipredictiva-cn1-codescan ---
Failed to find CN1 Project directory.  codenameone_settings.properties will not be loaded
Checking from project root and source compile root: C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\tarifataxipredictiva\cn1libs\cn1-codescan\src\main\java

-----< com.innova507.tarifapredictiva:tarifataxipredictiva-common >-----
Building tarifataxipredictiva-common 1.0-SNAPSHOT                  [4/4]
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.97:settings (default-cli) @ tarifataxipredictiva-common ---
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary for tarifataxipredictiva 1.0-SNAPSHOT:

tarifataxipredictiva ............................... SUCCESS [  2.657 s]
tarifataxipredictiva-cn1libs ....................... SUCCESS [  0.567 s]
cn1-codescan ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.587 s]
tarifataxipredictiva-common ........................ SUCCESS [  1.640 s]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  6.317 s
Finished at: 2023-02-01T12:52:34-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

[Test99 new Proyect](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LVBZPMCTTTEZxEYfwrh3S2_fPzyktTiN)

Comment: Which build did you send and to which platform? It looks like you did a local compilation instead of selecting the cloud or local build target as explained [here](https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/). If build fails on the servers we will need an error log from there.

Comment: The image that I attached shows how I do the construction and it is supposed to be in "https://cloud.codenameone.com/secure/index.html". No error is shown in the console and only the output that I previously copied. I suggest simulating the situation that I show with Netbeans 12 and windows 10 including the indicated extension.

I have done multiple tests with different projects and they all have the same ending.

Comment: That's a local compilation of the project. You need to use "Run Maven" or a similar target to send a build. See https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/

Comment: I am working with Maven and I reviewed the documentation and unless I am wrong I am following the necessary steps.

Attached 1 minute video. Previously, project "test99" was created with the extension "Codename One CodeScaner Library". It shows no errors and runs in the simulator without any problems.
The message "Build Successes" appears on the console and I wait 15 more seconds before stopping the video. The idea was to see the window that authorizes the use of the temporary signature, but this never happens. I've tried this several times and can't find the problem.

Comment: In the video [here](https://www.codenameone.com/getting-started.html) look around 2:36 where I send a build using a target. You need to select the maven options in NetBeans and send a build using the run maven targets.